# What tense is it when a commentator says "this is always happening" for a future move?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, future

You hear it often when someone is commentating on a turn based strategy game like chess. For example it's white to play and black has the good move RxB which cannot be avoided. The commentator will say "RxB is always happening so white should push his pawn".

The future is said like it's the present, "will happen" is replaced by "is always happening", is there such thing as the present-future tense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is an interesting one. What the commentator is implying here is that regardless of player X's move player Y's bishop will be lost. The inference is subtle between the two phrases.

Using the present progressive form of the verb indicates an ongoing situation, rather than something that is taking place in the future. Which, given this is commentary, seems appropriate to me.

> **Present Progressive:** "RxB is always happening"
>
> **Futue**: "RxB will always happen."

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html